# MATLAB Type::Even

Tags: matlab

I have looked through the examples of this doc:

[Type and property representing even integers - MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/type-even.html)

I have even copy-pasted Example 1.
But it seems I'm getting errors:

```
>> testtype(2, Type::Even),
testtype(-4, Type::Even),
testtype(8, Type::Even),
testtype(-11114, Type::Even),
testtype(4185296581467695598, Type::Even)

 testtype(2, Type::Even),
                 |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

The doc can be seen in my Matlab's Help window too.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

[I know I can test these in some other way. But I want to know why it is not working.]

Comment: It seems it has to do something with MuPAD.
Whatever that means.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the example to MuPAD or to the Matlab command window? See [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/first-steps-in-mupad.html)